# Adding a number to date where the number is in one cell and date is in another - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a date in column B and a number in column C (number of days) all the way down and would like add the value in column c to the date in column B.

```
|     A     |    B     |  C  |
--------------------------------
 Name        01/01/2016   5
 Name2       09/01/2016   10
 Name3       04/02/2016   3
```

In this case, row 1 would become 06/01/2016, row 2 would become 19/01/2016, and row 3 would become 07/02/2016.

I want to then check if the addition is less than TODAY, if the addition is equal or greater than TODAY, highlight the cell red.

Here's my code so far.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim myDate As Date
    For Each cell In Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    myDate =  DateAdd("d", ) 'stuck here
    If myDate >= Date
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    cell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made changes in your code. Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim myDate As Date
    For Each cell In Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
        myDate = DateAdd("d", CDbl(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value), DateValue(cell.Value))
        If myDate >= Now() Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The condition should be `If myDate >= Now() Then` Right ?

Comment: @newguy - Thank you for pointing it out, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Not related to your code. But how come the code doesn't run when I open the worksheet. I have manually run it from the VBA editor.

Comment: @user2771150 - Its working for me. Make sure while opening the workbook, active sheet is where your data is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this but I think answer given by [Kilian Hertel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5953251/kilian-hertel) is the preferred way to do this.

As running the macro whenever you open the workbook might keep on adding the date with the number in column C so it will just keep on increasing I don't know if that's desired or not.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wk As Worksheet   
    Set wk = Sheet1      'Change it to the preferred sheet number (!Not the Sheet Name)

    Dim FRow As Long
    FRow = wk.Range("B" & wk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Finding Last Row 

    For Each cell In wk.Range("B2" & ":B" & FRow)         'Loop from B2 to B & Frow

    cell.Value2 = cell.Value2 + wk.Range("C" & cell.Row)  'Add the Date with the number in the corresponding row of `C` Column

    If cell.Value2 >= Date Then      'Check if the date in column B is greater than or equal to Today's Date 

        'If yes the do this
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3   
        cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
        cell.Font.Bold = True

    Else: End If

    Next cell   
End Sub
```

Comment: can you add comments to your code or explain your code please? I'm very new to VBA.

Comment: Sure why not I'll do it wait.

Comment: your code behaved a little strangely. It kept on adding date on all empty rows.

Comment: it will do that if there were any blank cells within that range

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be able to do that with Excel normal formula and conditional formatting?

I wouldn't use VBA for that.

If you format the date correctly in standard format it shows a number. Just calculate DateCellNumber (Column B+ColumnC) in ColumnD and then i think you can do conditional Formatting with TODAY() formula.

Allright?

Comment: I would like to automate the entire column rather than applying conditional formatting each time i add a new row.

Comment: @user2771150 You can format the data as Table so that when you add new data you don't have to apply the conditional formatting again.

Comment: Also running the macro again whenever you open the workbook might keep on adding the date with the number in column C so it will just keep on increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve is as below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myDate As Date
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        Range("B" & i).Value = DateAdd("d", Range("B" & i).Value, CDate(Range("D" & i).Value))
        If Range("B" & i).Value >= Now() Then
            Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Range("B" & i).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Range("B" & i).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```